# Google Analytics shows false data

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm new with Google Analytics.
I have an app in Google Play which was built in native android programming - in Eclipse.
When I check Google Analytics it shows that the app had sessions in iOS, and also in countries that I don't see in Google Play Developer Console.
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: [Related](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/analytics/VeqGLRo08Go/fhmSalV5bn8J)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programing related.